# HTML5 video turns black in IE and Edge

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, html5-video

Independent composition doesn't seem to work for the rendering process of my video. My ads are broken too. They remain black and give an error:

> Independent composition is disabled for video rendering. This can
>   negatively impact performance

I'm using the GoogleIMA SDK.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680148(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The HTML5 video tag is an element that is explicitly targeted for
>   independent composition. Independently rendering and composing HTML5
>   video enables a fast and smooth media playback experience.

I don't know why this doesn't work, is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or intentionally done this way (Not sure since it's pretty weird that video gets dropped from independent rendering).
But i do know how to fix this. The way to fix it is to look for CSS animations/transforms on the `<video>` element. These are usually suspect of a `<video>` element being kicked out of independent rendering.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks it did the trick, I hope they will improve it since css properties being able to kick the video tag out of independent rendering is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

*For those that wandered in from a Google search like I did, but the marked answer does not solve your issue*

---

If there are no animations on your `<video>` element, but you are still getting this error, make sure you don't have the

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

property in the style it may also break Edge, with the solution being to remove this property or to pray that Edge goes away some-time soon.