# Getting weird error on microsoft edge when playing HTML5 video

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, microsoft-edge

Basically the title, whenever i play the video on firefox or chrome everything works fine. But on microsoft edge i get the following error:

Independent composition is disabled for video rendering. This can negatively impact performance.

Edge will play the first second of the video and then display "video couldnt be rendered". I can barely find anything about this error and have no idea how to go about fixing this or if this is just a bug on microsoft edge. On this website i saw something about disabling css on the video tag which i tried and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I find one article and one thread for this error.

In MSDN issues page it was marked as fixed. So if you are using any older version then try to upgrade to latest version may solve your issue.

[Independent composition is disabled for video rendering](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/14653084/)

In other SO thread, the solution for this issue was mentioned that,

> The way to fix it is to look for CSS animations/transforms on the  element. These are usually suspect of a  element being kicked out of independent rendering.

[HTML5 video turns black in IE and Edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933559/html5-video-turns-black-in-ie-and-edge)

So you can try these two suggestions may help you to solve your issue.

Comment: I have already seen both of those links, i disabled css animations and nothing and i have the latest version of edge, i hate edge such a garbage browser

Comment: I try to make a test on my side with Edge but not able to produce the issue. If possible, can you provide a sample or the site address which can able to produce the issue? We will again try to make a test and try to check the issue.